# Android Action bar or tab layout or what

Tags: android

i'm trying to design a menu/bar just like this one :

http://imageshack.com/a/img844/796/n1ft.png

And i don't know if it is an action bar or a tab layout or something else.

some tutorials links will be so helpful.

Comment: It looks like an ActionBar.

Comment: evrey tutorial i got dosent looks like that , i'm so confused

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/action-bar-changing-the-icon.png

for example that text and that icon

Comment: I still don't understand what your question is.

Comment: actualy i need to develop a bar just like that and i coudnt find a tutorial to show me how , i dont whant an icon or a text i just need buttons just like in the picture

Comment: [Google is your friend](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+actionbar+tutorial&oq=android+actionbar+tutorial&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3j69i64.6928j0j1&client=ubuntu-browser&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what your looking for. [android action bar](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html)
And [android hive](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/)

Comment: i have all the tutorials still i'm not thinkin well.